# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' in Java Spring

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

I try to create a website with spring. But when I try to coonect my project with my database and to work with it throw spring I get errors.I run  mysql server only. I 100% know that port, password and username are right. What am I doing wrong?
run mysql server

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

like this

application.propeties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/java_spring_blog
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

dependcies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.coursework</groupId>
<artifactId>CourseWork</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>CourseWork</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Model:

```
package com.coursework.CourseWork.Models;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Post {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private String title, anons, fulltext;
private int views;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getAnons() {
    return anons;
}

public void setAnons(String anons) {
    this.anons = anons;
}

public String getFulltext() {
    return fulltext;
}

public void setFulltext(String fulltext) {
    this.fulltext = fulltext;
}

public int getViews() {
    return views;
}

public void setViews(int views) {
    this.views = views;
}
```

}

When I try to run programm I got an exeption:`java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`
And another one:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
```

I think it's because due to thirst one.

Comment: Try with changing password for root user or create a new user/password and use it

Answer (score 0):

It works when I create a new user. Thanks to Ankit